# Derby query to create procedure or function to populate a given table

Tags: java, stored-procedures, derby

I have a table called myDates which has a parameter field ,i.e., date.

The date field is of type date. I wanted to populate the derby table with values and wanted to know if PL/SQL can work. I'm relatively new to derby and simply want to populate the table with dates for e.g., I would call the procedure with something like this

> CALL filldates('2018-09-01','2018-09-24');

where filldates will be my procedure.

The procedure I have built is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(IN dateStart DATE,IN dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN

    DECLARE adate date;

        WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO

            SET adate = (SELECT mydate FROM MyDates WHERE mydate = dateStart);

            IF adate IS NULL THEN BEGIN

                INSERT INTO MyDates (mydate) VALUES (dateStart);

            END; END IF;

            SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

        END WHILE;

END;
```

but this gives me an error which states that derby doesn't recognize declare and begin.

Can anyone explain this to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In Apache Derby (aka Java DB) a stored procedure is created using Java programming language. The procedure is Java code in a method with signature `public static void aProcedureMethod`. The stored procedure is created and stored in the database as a database object. The procedure is invoked using a SQL command or from a Java program using JDBC API. More info in the [Apache Derby's Reference Manual](https://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html#docs_10.14).

Comment: Okay, so something like CREATE PROCEDURE filldates(IN dateStart DATE,IN dateEnd DATE)
 PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
LANGUAGE JAVA
READS SQL DATA
EXTERNAL NAME 'org.apache.derbyTesting.functionTests.util.ProcedureTest.selectRows'

and then making a java program for the same??

Comment: can you give me a tutorial which I can reference to, to create a procedure?

Comment: This is an example from the reference manual to create procedure from SQL: `CREATE PROCEDURE SALES.TOTAL_REVENUE(IN S_MONTH INTEGER, IN S_YEAR INTEGER, OUT TOTAL DECIMAL(10,2)) PARAMETER STYLE JAVA READS SQL DATA LANGUAGE JAVA EXTERNAL NAME 'com.example.sales.calculateRevenueByMonth';`. In this the method `calculateRevenueByMonth` is the stored procedure's Java code. Then use the `CALL` to call the procedure from `ij`. `ij` is an interactive SQL command-line tool for Derby.

Comment: Here is a link to [an example stored procedure for Derby](http://carminedimascio.com/2013/07/java-stored-procedures-with-derby/). One can search online for more examples or tutorials.

Comment: where should i store the java class in? Should it be in the same folder as in where my database is??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179510/discussion-between-prasad-and-siddhant-sahni).

Comment: Maybe [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)  would better suit you - you can create stored procedures directly through SQL with that